# Arguments passed into function don't pass through

Tags: php, function, arguments

I have a php function that is defined like this

```
function dbinsert(&$sconn, $values, $userid, $table, $reason = '', $setnull = false, $echo = false, $tzbypass = true)
```

When I call the function I pass in variable as normal but when I reach the variable $setnull in the parameter list the variables stop passing in.  More specifically no matter what value I pass to the function the variable remains unchanged.

For instance if I call the function like this:

```
$qresult = dbinsert($sconn, $valuesqt, $_SESSION['usrid'], '<tablename>', '<reason information>', false, true);
```

The value for the $echo variable remains as false even through I have passed in true.  I feel like I must be missing something obvious here but I can't imagine what it is.

Comment: did you get the same effect with the `$setnull`?

Comment: Yes.  Same thing happens with $setnull, and with $tzbypass.  I'm totally baffled.

Comment: I just tested out and everything is working, also i never met such behavior.

Comment: @ArtNabWebmaster could you show how do you use those boolean variables, or maybe you called a different `dbinsert` function?

Comment: @ArtNab Webmaster check at the very beginning of your method that you receive `$echo` variable.

Comment: @HastaDhana - No, it's the only definition of the function.  PHP doesn't allow redefines anyway.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco - Neither have I.  I have no idea what to think of it.  When I output the variable at he beginning of the method it returns false regardless of what I pass in.

Comment: I figured it out.  The file had two references to the function, and the surrounding code looked identical so it was hard to tell which one was being used by the program until I back tracked by placing indicators of the program position.

Comment: @ArtNab Webmaster Things happen.